# How to cast NSSecureCoding to MKMapItem in Action Extension

Tags: ios, swift, nssecurecoding

I'm trying to make an Action Extension for my app where the user can add his current location along with some other data. I debugged the extension after sharing a location with Apple Maps App and found out that Maps sends four providers with following content:

- a vCard of selected location
- an Apple Maps URL for selected location
- a plain text which is the name of selected location
- a `MKMapItem`

All of the content above is in type of `NSSecureCoding`. Force cast to `Data` and initialising `String` with that data for vCard, to `String` for plain text and url succeed from NSSecureCoding, but I haven't found a way to create a `MKMapItem` object from the Data I receive.

Here's what I tried:

```
provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "com.apple.mapkit.map-item", options: nil) { (content, _) in
    let item = content as! MKMapItem

}
```

but it fails. I probably have to cast it to `Data` first but I couldn't find any initialiser for `MKMapItem` with `Data`

Answer (score 2):

Use NSKeyedUnarchiver

```
itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "com.apple.mapkit.map-item", options: nil) { (item, error) in

    guard let data = item as? Data else { return }

    do {
         guard let mapItem = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? MKMapItem else { return }
         print(mapItem)
    } catch {
         print("Error unarchiving mapItems, \(error)")
    }
```